# Why can't I see Tables/Sequences in Toad's Schema Browser?

Tags: oracle, privileges, toad

Using Toad 9.7.2 against a network Oracle DB (10g) I can't see any objects in the schema browser using the account information provided to me by my DBA. Using Oracle 10g installed locally, I see all objects in my local Oracle instance using the account I created which has all privileges.  I believe this is an instance where the account provided to me by my DBA does not have sufficient privileges in the DB or to the Oracle catalog?

Is there a specific privilege I need to request of my DBA for this user account to be able to use Toad's schema browser against the shared DB?

Thanks in advance to any/all replies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stupid me. There's a drop down on the Toad schema browser that allows you to change the view of tables you see for each owner. It defaults to the user you login as. When I change the owner to the actual table owner, I can see the tables fine.

Thanks for reading/replying.

Answer (score 4):

You need SELECT privilege on the tables in order to see them.

Log in to the database using the account you were provided. Issue the following select statement to see all the tables you have access to:

```
SELECT owner, table_name 
  FROM all_tables;
```

If you don't see any tables from the schema you think you should have access to, then you have a privilege issue.

Comment: I do see the owners/tables. I was probably not clear enough -- I can query the tables, but can't use Toad's schema browser, which provides some nice to have features.