# create synonym ora-01031 insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, schema, privileges, sql-grant, synonym

I need help understanding what grants/privileges a user needs to CREATE a SYNONYM when it points to another (different) schema object.

When I try the below, I get ora-01031 insufficient privileges, so obviously I am missing and failing to apply other needed privileges. I did search as well as I could but couldn't find anything specific to cross-schema synonyms.

```
CREATE USER test IDENTIFIED BY pw DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP;
ALTER USER test IDENTIFIED BY pw;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO test;

-- ... create a bunch of stuff in test...

CREATE USER READWRITE IDENTIFIED BY pw DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE    TEMP;
ALTER USER READWRITE IDENTIFIED BY pw;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO READWRITE;

GRANT SELECT ON GDACS.FIXALARMS TO PUBLIC;
GRANT UPDATE, INSERT ON GDACS.FIXALARMS TO READWRITE; 

CONNECT READWRITE/pw;

CREATE SYNONYM FIXALARMS for test.FIXALARMS;
ORA-01031 insufficient privileges
```

Comment: Have you [granted `CREATE SYNONYM` to the user](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7001.htm#SQLRF54350) and missed that out of the question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The documentation for [the `CREATE SYNONYM` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7001.htm) includes:

> **Prerequisites**
>
> To create a private synonym in your own schema, you must have the
>   `CREATE SYNONYM` system privilege.
>
> To create a private synonym in another user's schema, you must have
>   the `CREATE ANY SYNONYM` system privilege.
>
> To create a `PUBLIC` synonym, you must have the `CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM` system privilege.

You're trying to create a private synonym in `READWRITE`'s own schema, so you have to have to do:

```
GRANT CREATE SYNONYM TO READWRITE;
```

The object the synonym is pointing to is in a different schema, but that isn't relevant here.

---

If your new account is only going to access objects in the GDACS schema, and particularly if you have a lot of objects you want to grant access to, then as an alternative to having to create synonyms for everything you could [alter the new user's `current_schema`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20531823/266304) in each session - possibly [via a logon trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652320/266304).