# Cannot create SYNONYM in Oracle

Tags: oracle, ddl, privileges, synonym

My question is how to create a public synonym from our own schema?
I have already tried several times,

Example:

In my schema there is a table named account, so I want to create a public synonym for this relation.To create the synonym I entered the statement something like this,

```
SQL>CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM acc for account;
```

but after executing it,
I got the error

```
SQL> create public synonym acc for account; 
ERROR AT LINE 1:
ORA-01031:insufficient privileges.
```

I don't understand why this error is occurring.

I have also granted a select privilege for the table account using public keyword.

```
GRANT select on account to public;
```

Comment: This is a Oarcle's Error message. Why is the question tagged as mysql?
And also you have to give yourserf privileges about creating synonym not just seelcting from the table

Answer (score 0):

Give yourself privileges for that

```
GRANT CREATE SYNONYM TO READWRITE;
```

Possible dublicate:
[create synonym ora-01031 insufficient privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830023/create-synonym-ora-01031-insufficient-privileges)

Comment: Your answer was very helpful for me, but I made a slight change in granting the privilege ,since I want to create public synonym so I need to give the privilege

Comment: Since I want to create a public synonym so, I have to give a privilege like GRANT CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM TO READWRITE;                                  THANK YOU, your answer was very helpful.

Comment: Nice! Feel free to accept the answer as a valid one if you want