# How to create aliases in oracle without sys privilages

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to create aliases for tables in the sh schema that I have select privilege on, my schema is cs1761xx. I'm trying to get select privilages on those tables without having to preface sh.xxxx. How do I do this? The schema I'm in again is cs1761xx, also I'm not suppose to create a new user.

```
    SQL> create synonym customers1 for sh.customers;
    create synonym customers1 for sh.customers
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Comment: what shcema are you logged in with when you execute the above statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create synonym ora-01031 insufficient privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830023/create-synonym-ora-01031-insufficient-privileges)

Comment: As stated above the schema I'm in is cs1761xx, but it appears I DO NOT have create synonym privileges, nor create public synonym privileges, etc. According to the problem, I'm not suppose to create a new user either.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of create synonym, but the answer maybe that I can not achieve the aliases creation. Can someone please help?

Comment: Why isn't it a duplicate? You're doing the same thing and getting the same error, and need the same privilege to be granted to your user by your DBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DBA won't grant you the privilege necessary to create a synonym, and this is a course assignment that refers to 'aliases' rather than specifically to synonyms, and you only need to query the tables... then another option is to create a view instead:

```
create view customers as select * from sh.customers;
```

Also assuming you have the privieges to do that, of course. It's rather stretching the meaning of 'alias' though. (You can insert, update and delete too, but would need an instead-of trigger; that seems to be out of scope though).

Comment: This is actually what I was thinking the professor was intending. Thank you for your help. I will know soon enough what approach we were suppose to take.

Answer (score 1):

Use `alter session set current_schema = sh;` to avoid having to preface the schema name:

```
SQL> select count(*) from customers;
select count(*) from customers
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> alter session set current_schema = sh;

Session altered.

SQL> select count(*) from customers;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```